# Overwriting during a loop

Tags: python-3.x

I enter the matrix line by line, arrays (then you will need to perform different actions, this is more convenient). After that, I need to display a system of algebraic linear equations on the screen. To make it look nice, I check each of the arrays a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 (5 rows of the matrix) for dimension, if the number is greater than or equal to 0, then I attribute + to it, if less, then I do nothing. These updated numbers (strings) I enter b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 into the array. The problem is that when I output values b1, b2, b3, b4 and b5 to the console, then all these values are equal to b5. I can't figure out what the problem is

````
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore

init()

a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = a5 = b1 = b2 = b3 = b4 = b5 = P = Q = X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

det = det_check = 0
matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


def input_cof():
    global a1, a2, a3, a4, a5

    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX)
    print("Введите элементы матрицы 'A' (ВВОДИТЬ ЧИСЛА ЧЕРЕЗ ПРОБЕЛ ПОСТРОЧНО!):")
    print(Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX)

    print("Первая строка:")
    a1 = [float(i) for i in input().split()]

    print("Вторая строка:")
    a2 = [float(i) for i in input().split()]

    print("Третья строка:")
    a3 = [float(i) for i in input().split()]

    print("Четвёртая строка:")
    a4 = [float(i) for i in input().split()]

    print("Пятая строка:")
    a5 = [float(i) for i in input().split()]

    check_cof()


def check_cof():
    global a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5

    zero = float(0)

    k = 0
    while k < 5:
        if a1[k] > zero:
            b1[k] = "+" + str(a1[k])
        elif a1[k] == zero:
            b1[k] = "+" + str(a1[k])
        else:
            b1[k] = str(a1[k])
        k += 1
    print(b1)
    k = 0
    while k < 5:
        if a2[k] > zero:
            b2[k] = "+" + str(a2[k])
        elif a2[k] == zero:
            b2[k] = "+" + str(a2[k])
        else:
            b2[k] = str(a2[k])
        k += 1
    print(b2)
    k = 0
    while k < 5:
        if a3[k] > zero:
            b3[k] = "+" + str(a3[k])
        elif a3[k] == zero:
            b3[k] = "+" + str(a3[k])
        else:
            b3[k] = str(a3[k])
        k += 1
    print(b3)
    k = 0
    while k < 5:
        if a4[k] > zero:
            b4[k] = "+" + str(a4[k])
        elif a4[k] == zero:
            b4[k] = "+" + str(a4[k])
        else:
            b4[k] = str(a4[k])
        k += 1
    print(b4)
    k = 0
    while k < 5:
        if a5[k] > zero:
            b5[k] = "+" + str(a5[k])
        elif a5[k] == zero:
            b5[k] = "+" + str(a5[k])
        else:
            b5[k] = str(a5[k])
        k += 1
    print(b5)
    output_cof()


def output_cof():
    cycle = str(0)
    while cycle != "Y":
        global a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5

        print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX)

        #Here's the error, all the values of b are the same...

        print(f'''Введённая СЛАУ:
        
        |{a1[0]}x\u2081{b1[1]}x\u2082{b1[2]}x\u2083{b1[3]}x\u2084{b1[4]}x\u2085 = {a1[5]}
        |{a2[0]}x\u2081{b2[1]}x\u2082{b2[2]}x\u2083{b2[3]}x\u2084{b2[4]}x\u2085 = {a2[5]}
        |{a3[0]}x\u2081{b3[1]}x\u2082{b3[2]}x\u2083{b3[3]}x\u2084{b3[4]}x\u2085 = {a3[5]}
        |{a4[0]}x\u2081{b4[1]}x\u2082{b4[2]}x\u2083{b4[3]}x\u2084{b4[4]}x\u2085 = {a4[5]}
        |{a5[0]}x\u2081{b5[1]}x\u2082{b5[2]}x\u2083{b5[3]}x\u2084{b5[4]}x\u2085 = {a5[5]}''')```

P.S. I will attach an additional link to the file itself.

[Main.py][1]


  [1]: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BBgEcnApbE9qsA
````

Comment: because you have set all the variables to a list at the top and the list is mutable, so they will **all** be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the error like this. Lists are mutable.

So you have this:

```py
a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = a5 = b1 = b2 = b3 = b4 = b5 = P = Q = X = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# change one of the values in the list 
a1[0] = 10

# look what happens to b1 =>  it has changed !!!
print(b1)
```

result:

```
[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And all of the other lists will have changed similarly too !!!

So really you need to do this:

```py
a1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
a3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# and so on....

b1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```